# how to call nsuserdefaults to tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

i have two textfields and an array.

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[myArray addObject:textFieldHeader.text];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:myArray forKey:textFieldGroup.text];
```

textFieldGroup.text passing to tableview and

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

 array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[standardUserDefaults objectForKey:_passedFieldGroup]];

[self.tableView reloadData];


}
```

but how do i call these keys as sections and objects as rows when i go to table view?

Comment: Are you implementing the [`UITableViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you want to go through all of the stored keys in the NSUserDefaults?
That is not possible as far as I know. The only solution that comes to my mind is to store the keys seperate in a file or maybe in an array in the NSUserDefaults, too.